# How do I answer these questions?

Tags: linear-algebra

My professor gave us this question and I am unsure how to answer it:

We claimed in class that for a square symmetric matrix $A$ with eigenvector/eigenvalue pairs $(\mathbf e_i, d_i)$ we can write $A = EDE^T$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $d_i$ and $E$ is a matrix with columns given by the the $\mathbf e_i$.

Show that this is true by
   i) Showing that $AE = ED$
   ii) Observing that $EE^T = I$, produce $A = EDE^T$.

Using the above results, show that  we can write
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n d_i \mathbf e_i \mathbf e_i^T = EDE^T
$$

Lastly, show that we can express tr$(A) = \sum d_i$.

Comment: What have you tried?  Hint for i: what happens when you apply this to a standard basis vector?  ii is direct when you know i, just multiply.

Comment: I was getting confused as to how to start the question so I have not tried anything yet.

Comment: All claims in the question are wrong. Your professor probably wanted $A$ to be *real* symmetric and each $\mathbf e_i$ to be a *unit* eigenvector. The problem statement is true in this case.

Comment: Okay, if those statements were true how would you answer the question?